# I'm getting the error while doing build "Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved"

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.0 from/to telstra-repository (https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public): Auth scheme may not be null -> [Help 1]
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR]
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR]
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:46    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:47    /opt/bamboo_agent/xml-data/build-dir/NA-SVCCPC-JOB1 after install
build   17-Sep-2021 09:34:47    total 84

Comment: Firewall/Proxy `Auth scheme may not be null ??

Comment: Are you asking me to check firewall & proxy configuration?